# in rspec controller create post with current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

Models:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controllers:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @post = current_user.posts.creata(post_params)
  end

  def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:name,:user_id)
  end
end

RSpec.describe PostsController do
 describe "create post" do
  it "should create"
   user = create(:user)
   expect{
   post :create, params: { name: "new post", user_id: user.id }
   }.to change(Post,:count).by(1)
  end
 end
```

And this error:
ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: post

Comment: post :create, params: { post: {name: "new post" }}

Comment: and you also need to stub current_user: 

`allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) { user }`

Comment: {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts", :post=>{:name=>"new post"}}

Comment: Can you explain  allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) { user } –

Comment: you need controller to return `user` you just created, when you call `current_user ` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Comment: post :create, params:  { post: { site: "new post"} }
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) {user}

Comment: but not working

Comment: no routes match, this is no see my current_user

Answer (score 1):

On rails 5 you need pass the whole params structure. See below:

Rails 4:

```
post :create, post: { name: "new post" }
```

Rails 5:

```
post :create, params: { post: { name: "new post" } }
```

Your specs is also missing the current_user stub:

```
RSpec.describe PostsController do
 describe "create post" do
  before do
    user = create(:user)
    allow_any_instance_of(PostsController).to receive(:current_user) { user }
  end

  it "should create"
    expect {
      post :create, params: { post: { name: "new post" } }
    }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
  end
 end
```

Comment: Failure/Error: post :create, params: { post: { site: "new post" } }
     
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts", :post=>{:site=>"new post"}}

Comment: devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'}

resources :users do
 resources :posts do
  
 end
end

Comment: try append the format at the end:

          post :create, params: { post: { name: "new post" } }, format: :json